# "Stub!" error when mocking HTTP requests with Robolectric

Tags: android, maven, robolectric, android-testing, androidhttpclient

I have a test class annotated with `@RunWith(RobolectricTestRunner.class)`.

All tests fail on the following line: `Robolectric.addPendingHttpResponse(200, " ... ");`

This is how the failure looks like:

```
java.lang.RuntimeException: Stub!
 at org.apache.http.params.AbstractHttpParams.<init>(AbstractHttpParams.java:5)
 at org.apache.http.params.BasicHttpParams.<init>(BasicHttpParams.java:6)
 at org.robolectric.tester.org.apache.http.TestHttpResponse.<init>(TestHttpResponse.java:30)
 at org.robolectric.tester.org.apache.http.TestHttpResponse.<init>(TestHttpResponse.java:43)
 at org.robolectric.tester.org.apache.http.FakeHttpLayer.addPendingHttpResponse(FakeHttpLayer.java:47)
 at org.robolectric.Robolectric.addPendingHttpResponse(Robolectric.java:1056)
 at [my method]
 at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
 at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57)
 at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
 at org.junit.runners.model.FrameworkMethod$1.runReflectiveCall(FrameworkMethod.java:44)
 at org.junit.internal.runners.model.ReflectiveCallable.run(ReflectiveCallable.java:15)
 at org.junit.runners.model.FrameworkMethod.invokeExplosively(FrameworkMethod.java:41)
 at org.junit.internal.runners.statements.InvokeMethod.evaluate(InvokeMethod.java:20)
 at org.junit.internal.runners.statements.RunBefores.evaluate(RunBefores.java:28)
 at org.robolectric.RobolectricTestRunner$2.evaluate(RobolectricTestRunner.java:234)
 at org.junit.runners.BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.runChild(BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.java:76)
 at org.junit.runners.BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.runChild(BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.java:50)
 at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$3.run(ParentRunner.java:193)
 at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$1.schedule(ParentRunner.java:52)
 at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.runChildren(ParentRunner.java:191)
 at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.access$000(ParentRunner.java:42)
 at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$2.evaluate(ParentRunner.java:184)
 at org.robolectric.RobolectricTestRunner$1.evaluate(RobolectricTestRunner.java:175)
 at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.run(ParentRunner.java:236)
 at org.junit.runners.Suite.runChild(Suite.java:128)
 at org.junit.runners.Suite.runChild(Suite.java:24)
 at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$3.run(ParentRunner.java:193)
 at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$1.schedule(ParentRunner.java:52)
 at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.runChildren(ParentRunner.java:191)
 at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.access$000(ParentRunner.java:42)
 at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$2.evaluate(ParentRunner.java:184)
 at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.run(ParentRunner.java:236)
 at org.junit.runner.JUnitCore.run(JUnitCore.java:157)
 at com.intellij.junit4.JUnit4IdeaTestRunner.startRunnerWithArgs(JUnit4IdeaTestRunner.java:74)
 at com.intellij.rt.execution.junit.JUnitStarter.prepareStreamsAndStart(JUnitStarter.java:202)
 at com.intellij.rt.execution.junit.JUnitStarter.main(JUnitStarter.java:65)
 at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
 at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57)
 at com.intellij.rt.execution.application.AppMain.main(AppMain.java:120)
```

There is **no** problem with other features of Robolectric, aside from HTTP request faking. I'm using Maven. Any ideas?